# What songs got their charts renewed on Cytus 7.0?

Tags: cytus

When Cytus got updated to 7.0, one of the changelog is

> -Renewed charts for many songs in Chapter 1 - Chapter 3, providing new experience of epic songs.

<sup>(source on [Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/rayark.Cytus/posts/746115602123664), [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rayark.Cytus.full), and [App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/cytus/id485246824))</sup>

but... they didn't provide the list of the songs which got renewed, which I believe its purpose is to make players curious and surprise them. However, this also gives confusion since not all players can remember the level & chart of all songs. To make it worse (well, maybe), the scores of those songs don't get reset. In the end, there's really no indicator everywhere (official website & in-game) if a song got its chart renewed.

Personally, I could remember most of Lv.9 charts (since I still need to get Million Master on them), and I did realize Chapter 2's *Entrance* got renewed chart (which is certainly *harder* now...). But how about the other songs? Could anyone provide a list of chapter 1-3 songs which got their charts renewed (and possibly, including the level change)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiled from [Cytus Wikia](http://cytus.wikia.com/) and [Cytus Wiki*](http://wikiwiki.jp/cytus/?%A5%A2%A5%C3%A5%D7%A5%C7%A1%BC%A5%C8#medd5544) (Japanese site).

**Symbol**

```
✗         - no changes at all
✓ (x)     - only renewed chart, no difficulty change
✓ (x → y) - renewed chart & difficulty change
```

**Chapter 1**

1. Light up my LOVE

   - Easy: ✓ (2 → 3)
   - Hard: ✓ (6 → 7)
2. Ververg

   - Easy: ✓ (2 → 4)
   - Hard: ✓ (5 → 7)
3. Ververg ver.B: ✗
4. Chemical Star

   - Easy: ✓ (1)
   - Hard: ✓ (3 → 6)
5. Visions

   - Easy: ✓ (1)
   - Hard: ✓ (6 → 7)
6. Les Parfums de L'amour

   - Easy: ✓ (3)
   - Hard: ✓ (5 → 6)
7. Retrospective

   - Easy: ✓ (3)
   - Hard: ✓ (4 → 5)
8. The Silence

   - Easy: ✓ (1)
   - Hard: ✓ (7)
9. D R G

   - Easy: ✓ (3 → 4)
   - Hard: ✓ (5 → 7)
10. Secret Garden

    - Easy: ✓ (1 → 3)
    - Hard: ✓ (4 → 7)
11. Hot Air Balloon: ✗

**Chapter 2**

1. Iris

   - Easy: ✓ (3)
   - Hard: ✓ (7)
2. Sanctity: ✗
3. Sacred: ✗
4. Green Eyes

   - Easy: ✓ (1 → 4)
   - Hard: ✓ (6 → 8)
5. Nocturnal Type

   - Easy: ✓ (2)
   - Hard: ✓ (8 → 7)
6. Precipitation

   - Easy: ✓ (5 → 7)
   - Hard: ✓ (6 → 8)
7. Precipitation ver.B

   - Easy: ✓ (5 → 7)
   - Hard: ✓ (6 → 9)
8. Entrance

   - Easy: ✓ (6)
   - Hard: ✓ (9)
9. Precipitation at the Entrance I: ✗
10. Precipitation at the Entrance II: ✗

**Chapter 3**

1. The Riddle Story: ✗
2. Libera me: ✗
3. COSMO

   - Easy: ✓ (5)
   - Hard: ✓ (7)
4. Prismatic Lollipops: ✗
5. Otome: ✗
6. Spectrum: ✗
7. Halcyon: ✗
8. The Black Case: ✗
9. Saika

   - Easy: ✓ (5)
   - Hard: ✓ (7)
10. Saika ver.B: ✗